# What causes this signed int to unsigned int conversion using a ternary, but not shorts?

Tags: c++, c++11

When using a ternary operator within list initialization, what causes the implicit conversion of `int` to `unsigned int` (and similarly for `long long`) but not `short` to `unsigned short` (and similarly for `char`).

Specifically, I am surprised that the `i32v2` function compiles fine whereas the others do not:

```cpp
unsigned short f16(unsigned short x);
unsigned int f32(unsigned int x);

void i16(short value) {
    unsigned short encoded{value}; // narrowing, makes sense
}

void i32(int value) {
    unsigned int encoded{value}; // narrowing, makes sense
}

void i16v2(short value) {
    unsigned short encoded{false ? value : f16(value)}; // narrowing, makes sense
}

void i32v2(int value) {
    unsigned int encoded{false ? value : f32(value)}; // not narrowing, huh?
}
```

Complete example here: https://godbolt.org/z/fVTcrr

I am guessing the ternary operator implicitly converts `int` to `unsigned int` but I do not understand why it is unable to convert `short` to `unsigned short` similarly.

I would expect, if it was possible for `int`, then the ternary operator should also be able to convert any of the other `signed` types to the `unsigned` when possible:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the smallest unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2n
>   where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type.

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

Can someone explain this behavior, and if possible, reference the standard or applicable  cppreference page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says (quotes from latest draft):

> [expr.cond]
>
> Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard conversions are performed on the second and third operands.
>   After those conversions, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - The second and third operands have the same type; ... *[does not apply]*
> - The second and third operands have arithmetic *[applies]* or enumeration type; **the usual arithmetic conversions are performed** to bring them to a common type, and the result is of that type.
> - ...
>
> [expr.arith.conv]
>
> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way.
>   The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of scoped enumeration type ... *[does not apply]*
> - If either operand is of type long double ... *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if either operand is double ... *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if either operand is float ... *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, the **integral promotions ([conv.prom]) shall be performed on both operands**.
>     Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:
>
> ...
>
> [conv.prom]
>
> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_­t, char32_­t, or wchar_­t *[applies]* whose integer conversion rank ([conv.rank]) is less than the rank of int *[applies]* can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type *[evidently applies<sup>**1**</sup>]*; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.
>
> These conversions are called integral promotions.

So, in the case of `i16v2`, the second and third operands are `short` and `unsigned short`. Both evidently<sup>1</sup> promote to `int` on your system, and the `int` result of the conditional operator is then used to initialise the `unsigned short`.

In the case of `i32v2`, no promotions apply and the common type of `int` and `unsigned int` is `unsigned int`.

<sup>1</sup> I say *evidently*, because technically, `unsigned short` could promote to `unsigned int` on some exotic system where their size is the same, in which case `int` couldn't represent all values of `unsigned short`. The outcome that you observe shows that is not the case for your system, which is to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for `false ? value : f16(value)`, [integral_promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) is performed on the operands firstly. For [arithmetic operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions),

> If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

and

> The following implicit conversions are classified as integral
>   promotions:
>
> - `signed char` or `signed short` can be converted to `int`;

That means the return type of `false ? value : f16(value)` is `int`, then causes the narrowing conversion to `unsigned short`.

On the other hand, the return type, i.e. the common type for `false ? value : f32(value)` is `unsigned int`, then `unsigned int encoded{false ? value : f32(value)};` is fine.

> Otherwise, the operand has integer type (because `bool`, `char`, `char8_t`,
>   `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and unscoped enumeration were promoted at
>   this point) and integral conversions are applied to produce the common
>   type, as follows:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand
>     is converted to the unsigned operand's type.

For `long` or `long long`, they won't be *promoted* to `int`, then they don't have such issues.

Comment: Is the common type for `short` and `unsigned short` not going to be `unsigned short`?

Comment: @YorekB Integral promotion is performed at firstly, then the problem becomes what's the common type of `int` and `int`.